# CSS div hover affect child elements instead of the div

Tags: html, css

So I am testing out a product card layout and I am trying to make the box shadow effect appear when I hover over the product card. But the hover function only affects the div Product-Card hov's  child elements instead of the actual div itself. How do I fix it? Any help is much appreciated.

```css
.Product-Card{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

.hov{
  margin: 0 4px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.hov :hover{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px 0 rgb(44 44 45 / 7%), 0 0 20px 0 rgb(44 44 45 / 7%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Product-Card hov">
  <div class="Item-Layout">
     <div class="img-box">
        <img src="1.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="content">
        <div class="product-name">
           <p> Testing <p>
        </div>
        <div class="Price">
           <p>$10.40<p>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the space befor `:hover`

Comment: To apply hover on `.hov` you must use selector `.hov:hover`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your selector `.hov:hover`.

A space between the two means `:hover` on any child of `.hov`

```css
.Product-Card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.hov {
  margin: 0 4px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.hov:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px 0 rgb(44 44 45 / 7%), 0 0 20px 0 rgb(44 44 45 / 7%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Product-Card hov">
  <div class="Item-Layout">
    <div class="img-box">
      <img src="1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="product-name">
        <p> Testing
          <p>
      </div>
      <div class="Price">
        <p>$10.40
          <p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove space between `.hov:hover`

```css
.Product-Card{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

.hov{
  margin: 0 4px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.hov:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px 0 rgb(44 44 45 / 7%), 0 0 20px 0 rgb(44 44 45 / 7%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Product-Card hov">
  <div class="Item-Layout">
     <div class="img-box">
        <img src="1.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="content">
        <div class="product-name">
           <p> Testing <p>
        </div>
        <div class="Price">
           <p>$10.40<p>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```